# Is iOS in-app purchase not required if purchase or subscription happens in web app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Here's a scenario that's not clear to me in terms of whether it's allowed by Apple (even though I've seen other apps that actually do this):

1. User purchases or subscribes to a web app.
2. User then downloads related iOS app (i.e., it has the same functions and shares the same data with the web app) and can access the iOS app only by entering their user ID and password from the web app (so essentially the iOS app is free to download but not free to use).

According to the Apple Developer [FAQ page for in-app purchases](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies):

"Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected"

"Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected".

"Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Program License Agreement"

"Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App"

Does the last point contradict the other three?

Does the scenario I've seen where an iOS app is activated using the user ID and password from the developer's web app fall under the first three points, or under the fourth point? Why?

I presume it's also possible that the apps I've seen are violations that fell below the Apple radar, because the FAQ page also states the following:

"In general, the more expensive your App, the more thoroughly we will review it."

I'm really having trouble untangling what's allowed and not allowed and appreciate help getting a more clear understanding of these important rules.

Comment: Contact Apple or a lawyer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm speaking from experience here, I worked for two clients who each have an app available in iTunes, Google Play, and on the web. Both apps are monetized from subscriptions which can be purchased with in-app purchases from iTunes and Google Play and via credit card on the website.

Each app from their respective app store only offer the appropriate and allowed purchase method, e.g. the iOS apps only offer in-app purchases from iTunes, they never offered credit card purchases, nor do they link to directly to a webpage to pay by credit card.

Users are required to login and the subscription status (notably the expiry date), regardless of where they purchased from, is associated to their account in the database. This allows the users to access paid content from any device without having to subscribe again with a different payment provider. e.g. The user buys a subscription on Google Play and they can access the paid content in the Android and iOS app or on the web.

Both clients have server-side receipt validation in place which checks the status of the subscription on the expiration date.

Apple and Google seem to have no problem with this and there are many notable examples of apps doing exactly this; spotify and skype are a few that come to mind and they are big players. If your app is rejected for using this same practice then those apps are in violation too.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Do you think this arrangement would also be allowed if it were a one-time (license) purchase rather than a subscription, i.e., rule-wise there's no difference between one-time purchase and subscription purchase? Since your clients would avoid paying Apple's cut if subscriptions could only be purchased on the web, do they offer in-app purchasing as a way to get more subscribers (i.e., convenience for users) or do they offer in-app purchase because they are concerned they would be in violation of Apple rules if they didn't offer the in-app purchase option? Thanks.

Comment: @user9272 I can't say if apple is cool with a one-time in-app purchase for licence, see if you can find some examples on the app store of apps doing the same thing. The 70/30 split is high but it brings in far more purchases than web, but yes there is also the concern of being in violation.

Comment: What do these apps show in terms of subscription status? eg. if you subscribed on web do you show on mobile information about the subscription price / credit card / end date?

Comment: @Philippe Sure why not? It's entirely up to you how you want to represent this information to the user. With the apps I have worked on do show this information, it's good for UX.

Comment: Turns out we got rejected for showing the details of the web subscription so we switched to presenting just the name of the subscription.

Comment: @Philippe Did your app pass the review ?

Answer (score 0):

- basically you can purchase in web, however you should not add links or buttons or anything inside the app which will redirect to web for purchasing.
- if you do that, apple consider that you are targeting there customer & your account will be suspended
- install spotify and check premium tab

3.1.1 In-App Purchase:
If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, cryptocurrencies and cryptocurrency wallets, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase, except as set forth in 3.1.3(a) “Reader” Apps.

[App store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase)